# Installing doctrine data fixtures in symfony 2.1.4

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

Here is what i did:\

1. added following dependencies inside composer.json

   ```
   "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
   "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master"
   ```
2. ran following command at the terminal:

   php composer.phar update
3. Added following line to appKernel.php

   new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),

When I ran any symfony commands at the prompt, I got error as below:

```
Class not found: Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

Then i opened vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php and added following line:

```
 'Doctrine\\Bundle\\FixturesBundle' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/'
```

The error was gone and i could use data fixture easily.

My question is that should the namespace be automatically inserted into vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php when I run composer update or I had to manually insert the above line into the autoload_namespaces.php?
In documentation I didnt find anything that says to insert the namespace manually